# How to use RegEx re.search and group() to get multiple lines of matching data in python

Tags: python, regex-group

My text is this

```
text =

  [ BP2572 23,
    BP2345 34,
    BP2457 45,
    BP2866 56 ]
```

I want to extract just a portion of the text using `search` and `group()` `re` expression.

What I am hoping for is the following output

```
[BP2572, BP2345, BP2457, BP2866]
[23, 34, 45, 56]
```

I tried this code but I didn't get quite what I was expecting

```
>>re.findall(r"\s+[A-Z]{2}\d{4} \d{2}",text)

['\nBP2572 23', '\nBP2345 34', '\nBP2457 45', '\nBP2866 56']

>>re.search(r"\s+([A-Z]{2}\d{4}) (\d{2})",text).group(1)
>>re.search(r"\s+([A-Z]{2}\d{4}) (\d{2})",text,re.DOTALL).group(1)

'BP2572' #my expected output is [BP2572, BP2345, BP2457, BP2866]

>>re.search(r"\s+([A-Z]{2}\d{4}) (\d{2})",text).group(2)
>>re.search(r"\s+([A-Z]{2}\d{4}) (\d{2})",text,re.DOTALL).group(2)

'23' #my expected output is `[23, 34, 45, 56]`
```

Here I only got the first match.

How can use `re.search` and `group()` to get all the matching results and not just the first match?

Comment: *How can use re.search and group() to get all the matching results and not just the first match?* You can't

Comment: Your question no longer makes sense. If `text` is a list, you would not be able to use `re.search` against that list without a loop or a comprehension. Please dit your question to correct. Is `text` a multiline string or a list of strings? If it is a list of strings, how did you use it with `re.search`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to find multiple matches. Both `re.search` and `re.match` only return the FIRST match.

You need to use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) or [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) for multiple matches of a pattern.

You can do:

```
 >>> re.findall(r'^[ \t]*([A-Z]{2}\d{4}[ \t]+\d{2})', text, flags=re.M)
 ['BP2572 23', 'BP2345 34', 'BP2457 45', 'BP2866 56']
```

Or if you only want the first part:

```
 >>> re.findall(r'^[ \t]*([A-Z]{2}\d{4})[ \t]+\d{2}', text, flags=re.M)
 ['BP2572', 'BP2345', 'BP2457', 'BP2866']
```

Or only the second part:

```
 >>> re.findall(r'^[ \t]*[A-Z]{2}\d{4}[ \t]+(\d{2})', text, flags=re.M)
 ['23', '34', '45', '56']
```

Or both parts:

```
 >>> re.findall(r'^[ \t]*([A-Z]{2}\d{4})[ \t]+(\d{2})', text, flags=re.M)
 [('BP2572', '23'), ('BP2345', '34'), ('BP2457', '45'), ('BP2866', '56')]
```

Or, you can do simple splits:

```
>>> [line.split()[0] for line in text.splitlines() if line]
['BP2572', 'BP2345', 'BP2457', 'BP2866']
>>> [line.split()[1] for line in text.splitlines() if line]
['23', '34', '45', '56']
```

Comment: I want to use grouping to extract groups of data, my actual text contains a lot of groups so using findall() is laborious as I have to type a different match code every time. Can you write this code with re.search and group() ?

Comment: `re.search` only matches one element at a time. Either use `re.findall` with more than one match group and then pick the tuple apart or `re.finditer`

Comment: my text is inside a list so I cannot use split, please notice I have edited my "text" now.

Comment: NOW you can use `re.search` but needs to be with a loop or comprehension.

Comment: But if you have a list of strings, you can just do `[e.split()[1] for e in ur_list_of_strings]`